# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JS

Tags: javascript, token

I have this code, 
and I keep getting the error in the subject.

I didn't write this code by myself, but copy it from a website, and it's suppose to create parameters from the source of traffic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (localStorage.getItem('firstSource') == null) 
    {
    var firstSource;
    if ({{Page URL}}.indexOf("gclid") > -1) 
    {
        firstSource = "AdWords"
        console.log('adwords');
    }   
    else
        if ({{utm_source param}} != undefined) 
        {
        firstSource = "{{utm_source param}} / {{utm_medium param}}"
        console.log({{utm_source param}} + "utm");
        }
        else 
            if ( ({{Referrer}}.indexOf('google') > -1) || ({{Referrer}}.indexOf('bing') > -1))
            {
            firstSource = "{{Referrer}}"
            console.log('organic');
            }
            else 
                if ( {{Referrer}} !== ") 
                    {
                    firstSource = {{Referrer}}
                    console.log('referrer');
                    }
                    else
                        if ({{Referrer}} == ") 
                            {
                            firstSource = "direct";
                            console.log('direct');
                            }
    localStorage.setItem('source',firstSource);
    dataLayer.push({'event':'setTheFirstSource','firstSource':firstSource});
}
</script>
```

Please advise

Comment: what replaces the template fields?

Comment: maybe you should try to debug it yourself before asking on stackoverflow (see rules)

Comment: That piece of code won't work as-is; this is originally run on a server or frontend that replaces the `{{ ... }}`parts with values.

Comment: else block is the problem. Else block should be inside of curly braces if there is more than one line.

Comment: `{{Page URL}}` is not Javascript. It's a templating syntax that is supposed to be replaced, on the server, by the actual `"http://www.someurl.com"` before being sent to the browser where it will be run correctly.

Comment: @Pierre If I knew how to debug it - I probably would have done it.

Comment: That code should be use in Google Tag Manager, but it return error that can't be saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

else block is the problem. Else block should be inside of curly braces if there is more than one line.

Comment: ...but that's the case

Comment: That may not be the case but that will be out of the logic.

Comment: I don't understand. In OP's code, there _are_ curly braces around each code block. There _are_ `{` and `}`. `if ({{Referrer}} !== ") {               firstSource = {{Referrer}} ;
                    console.log('referrer');
                    }`. The curly braces _are_ here.

Comment: I am talking about js syntax not double curly braces ( String interpolation )

Comment: I know. I get it. Curly braces are here. `if (whatever) { firstSource = whatever ; console.log('referrer'); }`. Oh, just forget it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Which one of the else's should be in the curly braces?